# "to slice or cut (a finger)" in Traditional Chinese / Spoken Cantonese?

Tags: word-choice, usage, cantonese, word-requests, traditional-characters

Haven't managed to find a usage that speaks specifically to cut or slice open a body part.

Also seeing contradictions (or perhaps information gaps) between CantoDict and Pleco.

Some notes:

- CantoDict says '[開面](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/16614/)' means 'slice open' while Pleco describes this as a face-painting technique for Cantonese opera.
- '[切片](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/56427/)' seems like it could apply, though Pleco suggests more of a Medical context.

**How many variants can you make of *"I sliced my finger"* in Traditional Chinese / verbal Cantonese (slang)?**

Comment: If you mean the act that a surgeon/doctor makes a cut to open/gain access to some tissue or organ, then it's 切開 (with Traditional characers, literally 'cut [in order] to open'). However, if you need to express that someone has cut their finger as an accident and thus got injured you would use 切傷 (literally cut [to] injure).

Comment: Being a Cantonese native speaker, I would use 戒親

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that "開面" as "to slice open" in cantodict is **wrong**. Have a look at 國語辭典, these two terms are listed:

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000076573

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000099591

About "I sliced my finger", you may consider:  (u+20779). I guess that your computer / tablet needs to have a suitable font in order to display it.

[image: p1]

Usage:
Your colleague asked "What happened to your finger?"

Answer: "[比](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/bei2.Mp3)[張](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/zoeng1.Mp3)[紙](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/zi2.Mp3)[親](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/can1.Mp3)" (Click each character for its sound file :)

Roughly, "比張紙" is "by a piece of paper"; "親" is "sliced".

Be careful :)

Edited.

Of course you can :)

["比" (u+6bd4)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%AF%94), or ["俾" (u+4ffe)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BF%BE) are equal in this context, you can use either one, I quoted "比" just because it's simpler, has fewer strokes.

Now, here's another one: ["畀" (u+7540)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%95%80), which is the ancestor of the above two. It existed since oracle bone script, used commonly in literatures of yore. Unfortunately, nowadays this original character is not well recognised; that's why people are using "比" or "俾" most of the time.

Comment: Was able to use canjie input on my phone for '', thank you.

Is '俾' a suitable replacement for '比' in this context?

Comment: i edited the answer, cause it's hard to express clearly in comment :)

Comment: "比" ~= comparison; "畀" ~= give/allow; "俾" ~= allow/make sth happens .... These three characters have distinct usages.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "to cut or slice open a body part"?

If it is a small wound, you can say "" (http://www.zdic.net/z/85/js/20779.htm) or, less commonly, "鎅" (http://www.zdic.net/z/26/js/9385.htm).  e.g. "損".

If it is caused by slashes, you can say "劈" (http://www.zdic.net/z/16/js/5288.htm)

If there is a big open wound, you can say "劏" (http://www.zdic.net/z/16/js/528F.htm).  e.g. "劏開"

If such body part(s) is sliced away, you can say "片" (http://www.zdic.net/z/1e/js/7247.htm), which is pronounced as pin2 (http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-can/sound.php?s=pin2) in such usage.  e.g. "塊皮畀車葉片咗去" (a layer of skin is sliced away by the propellers).

Answer (score -1):

> *Haven't managed to find a usage that speaks specifically to cut or slice open a body part.*

剖開 - cut open. 
Examples: 剖開胸部 (cut open the chest);剖開腹部 (cut open the abdomens)